# Multiple RoutePrefixes per controller using MVC Attribute routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-routing

With the new MVC Attribute routing, I know you can assign multiple `Route` attributes to a single `ActionResult`, but I am looking for a way to do the same at the `RoutePrefix` level. I have a controller which, in every action, should be accessible by three routes:

`/Games/{Title}/Characters/{Route}
/Books/{Title}/Characters/{Route}
/Cinema/{Title}/Characters/{Route}`

I tried putting three individual `RoutePrefix` attributes, but I get the error `Deuplace RoutePrefix attribute`. If I try to use a comma-separated list, I get `Best override method for does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments`.

Is it possible to set up a `RoutePrefix` so that it takes the three routes I want for my controller?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Running a bunch of tests I found out that I can just add 3 `Route` attributes to the controller level and it works the way I want.

Edit: a better way to do it I found was using the regex match method

`[RoutePrefix("{Type:regex(Games|Cinema|Books)}/{SectionRoute}/Character/")]`

Comment: How would you do it without a regex?
Can I just add multiple attribute lines? `[RoutePrefix("prefix1")]    [RoutePrefix("prefix2")]`

Comment: @Zapnologica It's been a while since I did this but if I remember right you either do it like your example or you  comma separate them like `[RoutePrefix("prefix1"), RoutePrefix("prefix2")]` try them both and see what happens

Comment: Dont thinks that's possible. It will throw Duplicate RoutePrefix attribute.

Comment: And I think you should put end sign `$` at the end of the each strings to disallow Gamesssdlasd, Cinemasasdasd etc.

`[RoutePrefix("{Type:regex(Games$|Cinema$|Books$)}/{SectionRoute}/Character/")]`

Comment: https://github.com/asadmalik3/WebApiMultipleRoutePrefixAttribute
This allows multiple routePrefix.