# Asp.Net Mvc Multiple Attribute Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

I have a controller (CarsController).
I want to set multiple route to action in this controller. For example;

```
public class CarsController : Controller
{
     [Route("cars/create")]
     [Route("cars/edit/{id}")]
     public action CreateOrEdit(int? id)
     {
       ...
     }
}
```

But I can not. What's the problem?

Comment: Try this: `[Route("cars/{Type:regex(create|edit)}/{id}")]`, see similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24472455/6378815.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This is great work :)

Answer (score 0):

Following code is great work. Thank You Tetsuya Yamamoto..

```
    [Route("cars/{type:regex(create|edit)}/{id?}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateOrEdit(long? id)
    {
        await FillViewBag();
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            return View(await this.Database.Cars.Include(i => i.Files).SingleAsync(id.Value));
        }
        return View();
    }
```

When using in action

```
@Url.Action("CreateOrEdit", new { type="create"})
```